# VS Code Autocomplete Re-imports Package with Full Path

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Every time I want to add a widget by selecting it on the autocomplete list from VS Code, let it be a Container, Column, etc., the full path is re-imported. Sometimes the autocomplete list will also show multiple lines for the same widget. `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`' is already included on the file.

e.g.

```
import '../../../../../flutter_linux_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import '../../../../../flutter_linux_v1.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart';
```

Image here: [screenshot of autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1noGt.png)

It goes away if I run Flutter clean but comes right back. Any ideas to make this go away?

Answer (score 0):

Which extensions are you using? Might there might be some extensions which is overriding flutters default extension behaviour.
You can run `code --list-extensions` from command line to get all extension installed. You can post it here so that me or someone else can help you out.

Comment: Here is the extension list

766b.go-outliner
ccimage.jsonviewer
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2
Dart-Code.dart-code
Dart-Code.flutter
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
esbenp.prettier-vscode
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
GrapeCity.gc-excelviewer
luanpotter.dart-import
ms-azuretools.vscode-cosmosdb
ms-python.python
ms-vscode.azure-account
ms-vscode.Go
nobuhito.printcode
rust-lang.rust
usernamehw.errorlens
whatwedo.twig

Comment: Can you disable `luanpotter.dart-import` plugin and then try

Comment: No difference without `luanpotter.dart-import`

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of `luanpotter.dart-import` and I can confirm is does not change any Flutter existing behavior, instead it adds a brand new command call `Fix imports` that you must invoke yourself